# Javascript src property doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, src

It's a very simple one. The source of the webpage is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscript.js"></script>
<html><body>
<h1>It works</h1>
<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
</body></html>
```

I put the js at the very beginning.

in jscript.js, it's:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("test text from bill!");
</script>
```

But it doesn't show the text. If I embed the js into html, it works.

And it's strange that when I directly access jscript.js from a webbrowser, the content is like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscript.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript">
document.write("test text from bill!"); 
</script>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: a Script tag with a src attribute is not an include. As such, there's no document for the 'document.write' to write too. Even if there was, it'd write it before the opening HTML tag, which would also be pointless. Also your .js file has HTML tags in it, also wrong.

Comment: By using John's answer, it works now. the document.write can also writ the text to the browser correctly. Thanks anyway

Comment: @billtian: Just because it works doesn't mean it's correct. It's not valid to have the `script` where you have it. The browser is performing corrections, but it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the `<script type="text/javascript">` or `</script>` in your javascript file. In fact, that's what is breaking everything. Remove them and it should work properly.

Comment: @billtian  See comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't include tags in the JavaScript file.

Even if you remove them, your text will be written too early in the page, so I'm not certain that it will show up properly. Currently you're writing the text *before* the `<html>`.

I'm not certain your `<script>` location is even valid. Also, you've excluded the `<head>` of the document, which would be required.

Proper structure for your page to write to the `body` would be:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jscript.js"></script>
    <!-- your script will write the content right here -->

    <h1>It works</h1>
    <p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
    <p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
</body>
</html>
```